# What is the best way to make a conference call/broadcast video from an iPhone?

Tags: video, iphone

This is the scenario: there's a wedding and a couple of friends can't make it, because we're in different countries. One friend is willing to transmit the wedding live with his iPhone, but we haven't found anything that allows us to conference call (Facetime and Skype conference call seem to not be supported on iOS devices, but I'm not sure).

There's five of us that want to be connected simultaneously, perhaps the best option is to "broadcast" the call to a service such as justin.tv?

Comment: nice, creative question, +1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For broadcasting the video, you can use [Qik](http://qik.com/info/overview). It will allow for live interaction during the broadcast over chat. [Here's the iOS app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/qik-video-connect-plus/id424106070?mt=8).

Comment: Qik is the best app i have come across for broadcasting live video.

Comment: +1 for qik, the first and still best for broadcasting video... But there will be no voice chat with it. Maybe, and just maybe, we can multitask the phone, skype or something at same time, if we're lucky and there's enough 3G for it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm asking for too much. Tried Qik, but it was constantly freezing—over a wifi connection. In the end we're going async, uploading photos and video to Facebook. Still, it's the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Ustream Broadcaster ([iPhone App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ustream-live-broadcaster/id319362690?mt=8)). Whatever you stream from your iPhone can be watched at http://www.ustream.tv/user/yourusername

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Tried it but the web player (not the iOS app) was crashing Chrome and Safari